# Dynamic JavaScript files on Ajax Request creating conflict

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 with heavy usage of ajax to get Partial Views. If Partial view contains JavaScript then it is added as a new js file as shown in snapshot:

[image: Dynamic JS files on ajax calls]

so If I have a js function:

```
function checkValue(){
   //do work
}
```

on ajax call a new dynamic JS file will be added contained this function and it conflicts with old once.

myfile.js contained:

```
function checkValue(){
   //do work
}
```

and 1.js (dynamic file) will contain it too

```
function checkValue(){
   //do work
}
```

So when I call it due to presence in old file it call already present `function` which is outdated. How to solve this situation like new JavaScript replace old one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether something is defined and redefine it only if it is not:

```
var checkValue = checkValue || function () {
     //do work
};
```

If you want your definitions to override each-other instead of defining the function with a name, define them on the global object each time:

```
window.checkValue = function () {
     //do work
};
```

Comment: if it is defined still I dont want to use it because I need updated.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed Then redefine it every time. Don't check whether it exists.

Comment: Please read carefully if I define var checkValue in dynamic js file it again use var checkValue and global variable confliction occurs.